# Get periods by condition on PostgreSQL Server with EF Core without loading in memory

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I have the following entity in my database:

```cs
public class DbValue
{
    public DateTimeOffset TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public double NumericValue { get; set; }
}
```

And want to generate the following objects:

```cs
public class Period
{
    public DateTimeOffset StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to generate `Period`s by a condition where the value is above a certain threshold without loading all `DbValue`s in memory?

So when I have the following DbValues in my database:

| TimeStamp | NumericValue |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-04-01 02:00:00.000 | 8 |
| 2023-04-01 02:00:01.000 | 3 |
| 2023-04-01 02:00:02.000 | 4 |
| 2023-04-01 02:00:03.000 | 6 |
| 2023-04-01 02:00:04.000 | 3 |
| 2023-04-01 02:00:05.000 | 2 |
| 2023-04-01 02:00:06.000 | 9 |

And I query for `NumericValue` less than 5 I want to get two instances of `Period`, one with `StartDate=2023-04-01 02:00:01.000` and `EndDate=2023-04-01 02:00:02.000` and one with `StartDate=2023-04-01 02:00:04.000` and `EndDate=2023-04-01 02:00:05.000` but without loading all `DbValue`s from the database in memory.

Comment: I removed my comments. looks like i do not understand question and probably others too. What is input data, what in database, what you have tried?

Comment: I clarified my question. Is it now understandable

Comment: What if `NumericValue < 4`? How do you plan to detect ranges? And why do not do that on the client side?

Comment: The detection of the ranges is my problem. I don't want to do it on the client side as I have a massive amount of data but changes in the numeric values are very rare.

`NumericValue < 4` would result in
`StartDate=2023-04-01 02:00:02.000` `EndDate=2023-04-01 02:00:02.000`
`StartDate=2023-04-01 02:00:04.000` `EndDate=2023-04-01 02:00:05.000`

Comment: Well, i still do not understand why do you need periods. For further querying? It is something like time series?

Comment: Yes it is a time series (e.g. speed of a car) and I want to get periods where the car is driving faster than e.g. 10 kph. As the signals have very high frequency ~100Hz it is a huge amount of data to process if I have to do that client side.

Comment: Which database engine do you use?

Comment: PostgreSQL (now added in question)